# How can i use MapBox on Android

Tags: android, dictionary, mapbox

How can i display MapBox tiles on Android ? I tried using it with OSMDroid, and Nutiteq with no success. Is there a android library for MapBox ?

For example i used this code to implement MapBox on OSMDroid : http://blog.spatialnetworks.com/post/2012/07/using-mbtiles-on-android-with-osmdroid

```
XYTileSource MBTILESRENDER = new XYTileSource("mbtiles", ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode, 1, 20, 256, ".png", "http://example.org/");
DefaultResourceProxyImpl mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this.getApplicationContext());
SimpleRegisterReceiver simpleReceiver = new SimpleRegisterReceiver(this.getActivity());

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mymbtilesfile.mbtiles");

IArchiveFile[] files = { MBTilesFileArchive.getDatabaseFileArchive(f) };

MapTileModuleProviderBase moduleProvider = new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(simpleReceiver, MBTILESRENDER, files);

MapTileProviderArray mProvider = new MapTileProviderArray(MBTILESRENDER, null, new     MapTileModuleProviderBase[] { moduleProvider });

this.mMapView = new MapView(this, 256, mResourceProxy, mProvider);
```

But it didn't work, i want to load MbTiles directly from the web.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit**

[**Official Mapbox Android SDK is released.**](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/)

[Also, see Mapbox's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028496/how-can-i-use-mapbox-on-android/37285763#37285763)

*To people who downvote, I answered the question before the sdk exists.*

=============================================

I think [Nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/) looks pretty promising. Their API has a lot of features.  Also, their demo projects are inline commented. You can check out [this project](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/tree/master/AdvancedMap3D). Especially, [MBTilesMapActivity](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/blob/master/AdvancedMap3D/src/main/java/com/nutiteq/advancedmap/MBTilesMapActivity.java) might be something that you're looking for. The class shows how to work with mbtiles:

```
// 1. Get the MapView from the Layout xml
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
// 2. create and set MapView components
Components components = new Components();
mapView.setComponents(components);
// 3. Define map layer for basemap
MBTilesMapLayer dbLayer = new MBTilesMapLayer(new EPSG3857(), 0, 19, file.hashCode(), file, this);
mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(dbLayer);
...
// 4. Start the map - mandatory
mapView.startMapping();        
// 5. zoom buttons using Android widgets - optional
// get the zoomcontrols that was defined in main.xml
ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);
```

---

**You can also take a look at [my toy project](https://github.com/entryleveldev/mbtiles) which is modified from their demo. Basically, my app allows the user to input a url of a mbtiles file. Then, it downloads the file and loads it to the MapView.**

If you really have to stick with OSMDroid, [this](http://www.sieswerda.net/2012/08/13/integrating-osmdroid-part-2/) might be helpful. I haven't had a chance to try it though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know what linke should i put instead of "http://who.cares/" -> my mapbox link looks like this : "http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/username.map-f1rhoycw/page.html"

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. I think your links are dead.

Comment: It's ok, i made it work, but know i have a problem, everytime i change the map, the cache still remains, that means i get mutliple different colored tiles, like a bug.

Comment: Do you know how to clear the cache of osmdroid ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I'll check when I have a chance.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a android library for MapBox ?

The best way to use Mapbox on Android is the [Mapbox Android SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/)! It's the official codebase, an open source project that supports vector tiles, map animation, and a bunch else - and it's also designed to be easy to transition to from the system default maps.

Re:

> But it didn't work, i want to load MbTiles directly from the web.

Since an MBTiles file is a bundle of tiles that's usually quite large - and can't be requested individually - you usually won't load it directly just to show a map. The approach that the SDK takes is [dynamic caching, as shown in this example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/offline-map/). The example uses Mapbox, but the caching mechanism is general and would work with any tile server.

Disclosure: I work for Mapbox, and occasionally work on the core of our native code, including the Android SDK.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: And yet, for a question as vague as "Is there a android library for MapBox?” this is this most appropriate answer: “Yes, here it is."

Comment: In the future, Please declare any affiliation you might have with Mapbox when promoting their products/projects.

Comment: I've updated my comment to be more specific to the question, and reiterated my affiliation, which is also explicitly stated in my profile and elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that with the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), you can use your own tiles provider?

See [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) and [UrlTileProvider](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider).

Comment: Well it's a generic API.  I don't know MapBox specifically, but assuming it can serve tiles, then I don't see why you would not be able to use it.

Comment: Yes it works, I did it. But the device's resolution is not handled by the API, so you'll have to do it yourself (eg use 256x256 tiles for low-resolution devices and 512x512 tiles for high resolution devices). Mapbox provide their tiles in 256x256 and 512x512 (see https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/).

Comment: Here is a class used for this exact purpose. https://gist.github.com/calindotgabriel/7c22e81baa69af7bf274

Answer (score 4):

Mapbox team has started pre-alfa release of Mapbox maps on Android, so I would like to recommend it, just to try. I assume it's good to know that they have heard prayers of android developers.

[Mapbox for Android on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

OSMDroid is terribly documented, but the way they designed it makes it very flexible and self-explanitory if you look at the implementable methods. Here is how you use Mapbox tiles with OSMDroid as of January 2015.

```
    mvMap = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    String mapCode = "mapbox.streets";
    final String accessToken = "myAccessToken";

    OnlineTileSourceBase customTileSource = new XYTileSource("MapBoxSatelliteLabelled",
            ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_aerial, 1, 19, 256, ".png", new String[]{
            "http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/" + mapCode + "/",
            "http://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/" + mapCode + "/",
            "http://c.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/" + mapCode + "/",
            "http://d.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/" + mapCode + "/"}){

        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
            String str = super.getTileURLString(aTile) + "?access_token=" + accessToken;
            return str;
        }
    };

    TileSourceFactory.addTileSource(customTileSource);

    mvMap.setTileSource(customTileSource);
```

Quick tip: If you're using Android Studio, use break points to get the value of any variable. This helps with debugging and understanding unfamiliar code. That's how I figured out that getTileURLString() returns the full URL of the tile.

Comment: Is it possible to use MBTiles file from online server storage such as http://www.example.com/mytile.mbtiles?