# Reduce DPI of Google Map on Android App (to Save Data)

Tags: android, google-maps

We have an app which uses Google Map API as its main source of information/data and is full screen all the time, it tracks the user as they move with specific overlays built for this app.

The data usage on high DPI devices is a lot higher than non HD devices and we are trying to find a way to reduce this data usage.

The Samsung Tab S 10.5 with a screen resolution of *2560 x 1600.* In semi-accurate tests performed by us we confirmed that the tablet is using approx 1.8-2.5 times as much data as the lower screen resolution of the Note 10.1 with a screen resolution of *1280 x 800.*

*Research so far:*

I have done semi-accurate data tests

- I monitored data using a Data Monitor Application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en
- I created fake data and both apps did exactly the same map representation
- I ensured both tablets were at the same zoom level
- I ran the map sequence over approx 8 hours, at 50kph, approx 400km

Data Results were:

- Note 10.1: 430 MB
- Tab S 10.5: 850 MB

*Solutions I have researched so far:*

There are a number of people having similar problems online, a quick search on Stackoverflow shows.

- Some people talk about the 256px tiles vs the 512px tiles, and trying to force tablet to load 256 (on web only and not android)
- Some people are implementing different mapping into their applications (E.g. Mapbox [How can i use MapBox on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028496/how-can-i-use-mapbox-on-android) )

I am hoping to find someone who has come across this before or knows a solution. Can we force the SDK/API to only load lower DPI images?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of factors that influence the data usage.
Since it only caused me 18mb to cache a 50x30km area, 800mb doesn’t seems to make a lot of sense.
One thing I would do to test it out is to set the DPI of 2 tablet to be the same and do the same tests again to see if they would get the same data usage.
You can modify your DPI like this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-verizon/general/root-want-to-modify-dpi-t2960644

Comment: However even if the result suggest that it is the DPI, I don't think there exist options for the map tile size in the Android API, but you can try to enable caching to improve the data usage:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions